# How to Clone SQL Azure DBs in VSTS - The databases 'A' in server 'sql01' and 'B' in server 'sql01' are already in a replication relation

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-devops

I am trying to configure my release process in VSTS to clone my live database to my staging environment before deploying the buld to staging. FOllowing guidelines here...

http://community.idera.com/blog/b/community_blog/posts/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-database-on-windows-azure-sql-database

and here...

https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/creating-a-staging-database-instance-from-a-production-instance-on-windows-azure-sql-database/

I have got it largely working though I get the following error when I run the command...

```
CREATE DATABASE [Staging] AS COPY OF [Operational]
```

> The databases 'Operational' in server 'sql01' and 'Staging' in server
>   'sql01' are already in a replication relation.

This is preceeded by...

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [Staging]
```

I can configure the build server to continue regardless but I still get nasty yellow warnings coming up. I'm looking to either suppress this in some way as a workaround or to do whatever is necessary to stop the error from coming up in the first place. The end result is as desired, the SQL database is successfully copied.

It feels like there's some other cleanup I need to do beforehand other than simply dropping the original database (if it exists!)

After the step above I then do this, which forces the release process to 'wait' until the Database is ready...

```
DECLARE @COPY_DATA int
SET @COPY_DATA = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_database_copies
WHILE (@COPY_DATA > 0)
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    SET @COPY_DATA = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_database_copies
END
```

...which can take some time. This completes with no errors at all.

To compound my woes, as time has gone on I have been unable to consistently ensure completion at each stage, leading to spurious fails. Sometimes the DROP won't finish. If I check it's existence in Master then It's gone but Create will fall over because it's still there.

---

For those reading on later, what follows is the solution I ended up with that was the most reliable.

**NOTES**
 - Powershell is more reliable than SqlCommand
 - Azure's API and the underlying database sometimes get out os sync for a while leading to a conflicting state between the two

In order to clone my production to staging I did the following...

Step 1: Azure Powershell Task (Clear Staging)

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "Production" -ServerName "sql01" -DatabaseName "Staging" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Step 2: Azure SQL Task (Drop Database) - Just to be sure!

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [Staging]
```

Step 3: Azure Powershell Task (Recreate Staging from Live)

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName "Production" -ServerName "sql01" -DatabaseName "Operational" -CopyResourceGroupName "Production" -CopyServerName "sql01" -CopyDatabaseName "Staging"
```

Step 4: Azure SQL Task (Await Sync) - Just in case!

```
DECLARE @COPY_DATA int
SET @COPY_DATA = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_database_copies
WHILE (@COPY_DATA > 0)
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    SET @COPY_DATA = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_database_copies
END
```

Step 5: Azure Powershell Task (Generate BacPac)
(I'm not going into that here as it's a whole other topic).

Once the release moves to Production I call the cleardown process again so Staging is only ever transient.

Comment: How about New-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Database​Copy PowerShell command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-copy-database-to-new-server-powershell

Comment: Is there a matching cmdlet for removing a database with AzureRm? I tried the classic version and found it no more reliable than a DROP command and far more difficult to write!

Comment: If I can get a working chain for this I'll post it all up.

Comment: This article seems to be someone using Powershell with similar problems, their workarounds don't seem like they fit my scenario though. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Remove-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/remove-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-3.8.0) and [New-​Azure​Rm​Sql​Database​Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabasecopy?view=azurermps-3.8.0) command to delete a database and then create a database copy.

Add an "Azure PowerShell Script" task in your build definition and configure it to use "Azure Resource Manager" to connect to your Azure Account like following:
[image]
The PowerShell script I use:

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "resourcegourpname" -ServerName "servername" -DatabaseName "databasecopy"

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName "resourcegourpname" -ServerName "servername" -DatabaseName "database" -CopyResourceGroupName "resourcegourpname" -CopyServerName "servername" -CopyDatabaseName "databasecopy"
```

Comment: Is there a way with Powershell to check if the database exists before attempting the Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase command?

Comment: To answer my comment above -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue was just the ticket. Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase seems MORE reliable but not entirely. New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy means I don't get the silly error message that the SQL command gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the copy process hasn’t finished, it will throw the error that you get. The workaround is as you said that you can wait the process finishing.
On the other hand, you can try to use [New-AzureRMSqlDatabaseCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabasecopy?view=azurermps-3.8.0) cmdlet and check the result.

> The New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy cmdlet creates a copy of an Azure SQL
>   Database that uses the snapshot of the data at the current time

Comment: That isn't it. The error occurs when I call the Create command to start the copy. I then wait for the process to finish. I tried using Powershell scripts to do the first, drop stage. The biggest difficulty I've found with all of this is getting any kind of reliability. Whether using SQL or Powershell a drop followed by a copy seems to be very inconsistent on output. Sometimes the drop won't have finished before the create starts despite checking that it exists and being told no. Admittedly Powershell is NOT my Forte.

Comment: Potentially a previous copy could be unfinished somewhere but the main error IS consistent every single time and my wait script indicates completion from the previous run. I guess I need to know what could indicate that something has been leftover and where so I can clear up. After all, the target DB from before will have been dropped so I'm a bit stumped.